# Send Form Group to another components, Form control value is empty why?

Tags: javascript, angular

If i send the form group [formData] and spectific control name to another component it has some form control with value,but when i try to get the form control value its empty why?? Actually form control has value.

Parent Component:

```
<app-custom-dropzone [field]="'qImage'" [formData]="questionForm"(onFormGroupChange)="onChange($event)"></app-custom-dropzone>
```

Child Component:

```
 @Input() field: string;
  @Input() data: any;
  @Input() formData: FormGroup;
  @Output() onFormGroupChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<FormGroup>();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    console.log(this.formData,"form")
    console.log(this.formData.value,"hey")
   
  }
console.log(this.formData,"form")
console.log(this.formData.value,"hey")
```

This is the console of this.formData

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYhhA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk5MA.png)

This is the console of this.formData.value

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tgVq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EIVP.png)

form control qImage has value but it show empty when i get the value if the control

Answer (score 0):

First, when use Decorator **@Input**, If the value is set asynchronous, it is not available in the ngOnInit in the subcomponent, so **console.log(this.formData.value,"hey")** empty is normal.
Second, and **console.log(this.formData,"form")** can print normally, because after the console point open, the browser again queries the value of the object and re-rendered in the console.